# Google Play Games RealTime Multiplayer Add Images

Tags: android, real-time, google-play-games

I am making a simple multiplayer game in Android, have implemented Google Play Games Real-Time Multiplayer API and it works as expected([RealTime Api](https://developers.google.com/games/services/common/concepts/realtimeMultiplayer)). However, I am trying to send my profile picture image to the other participant or send e.g a small image for both of them to see at the same time. Is this possible with the provided API or do I need to write a custom implementation for this?

Answer (score 0):

You want to show the player's icon right? You might want to check this related [SO post 1](https://stackoverflow.com/a/42547666/5995040) and [SO post 2](https://stackoverflow.com/a/22680199/5995040). They both use [ImageManager](https://developers.google.com/android/reference/com/google/android/gms/common/images/ImageManager) and you can also try using [**`getIconImageUri()`**](https://developers.google.com/android/reference/com/google/android/gms/games/multiplayer/Participant.html#getIconImageUri()).

> Returns the URI of the icon-sized image to display for this participant. If the identity of the player is unknown, this will be the automatch avatar icon image for the player. It may also be null if the player simply has no image.

Comment: Not necessarily setting the player's icon, but rather the other player's icon. Like it needs to be stored somewhere temporarily on the cloud in order for the other participant to retrieve it.